# Write Scheme data structures so they can be eval-d back in, or alternative

Tags: scheme, eval, racket

I'm writing an application (A [juggling pattern animator](http://github.com/jmillikan/Yet-Another-Juggling-Animator)) in PLT Scheme that accepts Scheme expressions as values for some fields. I'm attempting to write a small text editor that will **let me "explode" expressions into expressions that can still be eval'd but contain the data as literals** for manual tweaking.

For example,

```
(4hss->sexp "747")
```

is a function call that generates a legitimate pattern. If I eval and print that, it becomes

```
(((7 3) - - -) (- - (4 2) -) (- (7 2) - -) (- - - (7 1)) ((4 0) - - -) (- - (7 0) -) (- (7 2) - -) (- - - (4 3)) ((7 3) - - -) (- - (7 0) -) (- (4 1) - -) (- - - (7 1)))
```

which can be "read" as a string, but will not "eval" the same as the function. For this statement, of course, what I need would be as simple as

```
(quote (((7 3...
```

but other examples are non-trivial. This one, for example, contains structs which print as vectors:

```
pair-of-jugglers
; -->
(#(struct:hand #(struct:position -0.35 2.0 1.0) #(struct:position -0.6 2.05 1.1) 1.832595714594046) #(struct:hand #(struct:position 0.35 2.0 1.0) #(struct:position 0.6 2.0500000000000003 1.1) 1.308996938995747) #(struct:hand #(struct:position 0.35 -2.0 1.0) #(struct:position 0.6 -2.05 1.1) -1.3089969389957472) #(struct:hand #(struct:position -0.35 -2.0 1.0) #(struct:position -0.6 -2.05 1.1) -1.8325957145940461))
```

I've thought of at least three possible solutions, none of which I like very much.

Help me out before I start having bad recursion dreams again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Specifically, trying to produce a file with `eval`-able code seems like a strange choice.  In any case, creating a serialization of random values is a problem when you're dealing with structs -- since there could be different structs with the same name.  Some points that might be relevant for you:

- There is an undocumented library `scheme/fasl` that can read and write values in binary format (useful for large data).
- There is also `mzlib/pconvert` -- a library that DrScheme uses to print values as expressions that can be evaluated (but this won't work on all kinds of data).
- If you want to use structs that are very easy to write in a readable form, then you can use "prefab" structs.

(For more details it's probably best to ask on the mailing list.)

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without more details, but I think that the prefab option can work pretty well.  (I tried your thing -- the graphics is impressive, but I couldn't figure out the interface.  I'm not a juggler though...)

Comment: Thanks for looking! The interface really isn't very good yet. I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: If you're still curious about what it can do, I finally left some instructions and examples on the Wiki page on github.